# How to draw this Chart using google chart?

Tags: jquery, charts, google-visualization

[snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8InbE.png)

Hello everyone, i need to draw this graph using google charts. Can anyone help me draw this kind of graph ?

I tried this approach first, but not getting desired output

```
function drawProdListChart() {
    //var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    //    ['Product', 'Sales', { role: "style" }],
    //    ['Product A', 50000, '#FFC000'],
    //    ['Product B', 60000, '#3FC099'],
    //    ['Product C', 26300, '#ED7D31'],
    //    ['Product D', 51100, '#FFC000'],
    //    ['Product E', 13000, '#73A4FA'],

    //]);
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Category', 'V1', 'V2', 'V3','V4', 'V5'],
        ['Vodka', 43000, 65000, 60000,65000,60000],
        ['Gin', 43000, 65000, 60000, 65000, 60000],
        ['Wine', 43000, 65000, 60000, 65000, 60000]
    ]);
    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
    
    
    var options = {
        
            legend: { position: 'bottom', maxLines: 3, textStyle: { fontSize: 7 } },
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            width: 400,
            height: 250,
            bar: { groupWidth: '75%' },
            vAxis: { gridlines: { count: 4 }, textStyle: { fontSize: 8 } },
            hAxis: { textStyle: { fontSize: 7 } },
        
    };
    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("prodListChart"));
    chart.draw(view, options);
    
}
//html
<div id="prodListChart"></div>
```

Result :
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuOiY.png)